# Reduce space between two plots in Rmarkdown html_output

Tags: html, r, shiny, r-markdown

With the provided code I get this html output from a shiny app.

**My question is: How can I reduce the white space (red arrow) in the html output:**

**Background:** Although I made pdf output work locally, after deploying it does not work. Not because of the code. I tried it with a much less coded app and it worked. So my original code is to large to render a pdf output. Therefore I decided to go back to html output:

[image]

**logo.png**

[image]

**app.R**

```
# Global variables can go here
n <- 200


# Define the UI
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  numericInput('n', 'Number of obs', n),
  plotOutput('plot'),
  downloadButton('report', 'Generate Report')
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    hist(runif(input$n))
  })
  
  # create markdown report  ----------------------------------
  
  output$report <- downloadHandler(
    filename = "report.html",
    content = function(file) {
      td <- tempdir()
      tempReport <- file.path(td, "report.Rmd")
      tempLogo <- file.path(td, "logo.png")
      file.copy("report.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
      file.copy("logo.png", tempLogo, overwrite = TRUE)
      
      params <- list(scores = input$n)
      
      rmarkdown::render(tempReport, output_file = file,
                        params = params,
                        envir = new.env(parent = globalenv())
      )
    }
  )
  
}

# Return a Shiny app object
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**report.Rmd**

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
output: 
  html_document:
params: 
    scores: NA
---

```{r echo=FALSE}
library(htmltools)
div(style = 'width:50px; height:50px, top:-90px; right:0; padding:10px',
    img(src = knitr::image_uri("logo.png")),
    alt = 'logo')
```


```{r rectangle, echo=FALSE}
library(draw,)
drawBox(x =1.3, y = 4.5, width = 2.5, height = 1)
```


```{r, echo=FALSE}
hist(runif(params$scores))
```


<dl>
---
  <dt>Definition list</dt>
  <dd>Is something people use sometimes.</dd>

  <dt>Markdown in HTML</dt>
  <dd>Does *not* work **very** well. Use HTML <em>tags</em>.</dd>
</dl>
---
````

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you use Flexdashboard because you can easily style things. In your case you can use the Row {data-height=X} to solve your problem.

It is still an HTML document!

````
---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    css: optional.css
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE,context="server"}
library("knitr")
library(htmltools)
```

Row {data-height=200}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


```{r echo=FALSE}
div(style = 'width:50px; height:50px, top:-90px; right:0; padding:10px',
    img(src = knitr::image_uri("logo.png")),
    alt = 'logo')
```

Row {data-height=200}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r rectangle, echo=FALSE}
library(draw,)
drawBox(x =1.3, y = 4.5, width = 2.5, height = 1)
```

Row {data-height=500}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------


```{r, echo=FALSE}
hist(runif(params$scores))
```
````